# MMCV: Log validation loss every k iteration in EpochBasedRunner

Tags: pytorch, openmmlab

I am using mmdet3D to train a model and I would like to log the validation loss every k iterations while using EpochBasedRunner. If the loss is logged via Tensorboard log file, it would be even better. How should I set my config then?